# Plotting the influence of the second factor after excluding the influence of the first factor [R, lm(), lmer()]

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lm, ggplot2

I am conducting regression analysis and multilevel modeling in R using `lme4` package. I would like to plot the influence of `treatment_type` on `score`, which includes three levels, after excluding the influence of `time`.

```
fit1 <- lm (score ~ time)
fit2 <- lm (score ~ time + treatment_type)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(y= resid(fit1), x = treatment_type, group = treatment_type, col = treatment_type))+
    geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

I remember someone is plotting this way, but cannot find any information online and actually don't know how to even google this.

**First**, do you think this is the appropriate approach?

**Second**, can this also be used when including interaction between time and treatment type?

```
fit1 <- lm (score ~ time)
fit3 <- lm (score ~ time + time : treatment_type)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(y= resid(fit1), x = treatment_type, group = treatment_type, col = treatment_type))+
    geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

**Third**, can this also be used when fitting multilevel models?

Please and thank you!

```
fit4 <- lmer (score ~ time + (1|group))
fit5 <- lmer (score ~ time + treatment_type + (1|group))
ggplot(data = dat, aes(y= resid(fit4), x = treatment_type, group = treatment_type, col = treatment_type)) +
 geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

---

**EDIT**
This is a more concrete demonstration of what I would like to do.

```
require(ggplot2)
head(warpbreaks)
attach(warpbreaks)
fit1 <- lm (breaks ~ tension - 1)
fit2 <- lm (breaks ~ tension + wool - 1) 
ggplot(data = warpbreaks, aes(y= resid(fit1), x = wool, group = wool))+
        geom_boxplot()
```

The following graph clearly demonstrates the wool breaks are more at wool A as opposed to wool B after excluding the influence of `tension`:

[image]

```
fit3 <- lm (breaks ~ tension + wool:tension - 1) 
ggplot(data = warpbreaks, aes(y= resid(fit1), x = wool, group = wool, col = tension))+
        geom_boxplot() + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = tension), se = F)
```

summary(fit3)

[image]

Noting wool A is the reference level here, the difference of wool type is only influential at tensionL (i.e. tension is low).

The following graph shows that the residual is lower at wool B when tension is low or high, whereas residual is slightly higher at wool B when tension is mediate. Interaction is significant only at low tension, where wool A is significantly higher than B.

[image]

I am wondering if this is a plausible approach.

Comment: Are trying to do model validation by plotting residuals and inspecting their shape/pattern, or do you want to have a final graphical representation of your model fit with confidence intervals etc.?

Comment: Hi @Stefan. I am not trying do model validation using residual plots. I guess, not trying to represent the model fit, either.. What I would like to do is, I fit `fit1` and `fit2`, and confirmed with AIC that `fit2` is better. SO, I would like to show that how different types of treatments influences the results after excluding the influence of `time`. Pleaes let me know if my phrasing does not make sense, or if this is what you mean by "_to have a final graphical representation of your model fit with confidence intervals etc_". Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to provide more detail on your experiment, the involved variables, data structure etc. I also don't know what you mean by "after excluding the influence of time"... Since you are using the `resid()` function, you are plotting the residuals of your model fit.

Comment: I see. It sounds like the approach may not be used that much (or potentially at all.) What I understand residual is the value represents the gaps between the estimated values and the observed values. So, `resid(fit1)` should represent the values that were not explained by `time` factor in `fit1`. So, I thought plotting residual separately for another factor, `treatment_type`, may represent the how much difference across levels of treatment_type can be seen after excluding `time` factor.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will add more concrete explanation in my question above.